# Get wifi working Lenovo Thinkpad t440 on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, drivers, lenovo

I got an Lenovo Thinkpad t440 but I cannot get my wifi working with a fresh install.
Which drivers should I need to download so I am able to run the wifi?

I did an  `lshw -c network` and I got an `*-network UNCLAIMED` and an `iwconfig` but there is no interface associated and also a `rfkill list all` but I get the Bluetooth.

people: if some help me, could you give me the link to the deb files so I can install manually. I can't have get my ADSL internet working via Ethernet cable.

Thanks

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of: lspci -nn | grep 0280 Thanks.

Comment: 03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:08b2] (rev 83)

Comment: We also need to see: modinfo iwlwifi | grep -i 08b2 and also: dmesg | grep iwl Thanks.

Comment: @chili555 The first command returned nothing. The second is shown here http://m.imgur.com/y02xdVh sorry if I am showing you but I have no internet connection in this notebook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why you dont connect your pc over ethernet and update your ubuntu version with 
`sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` ? then your wireless card will work whitout any problems ;) and you are on the right way you have a thinkpad and you install linux :D (i use a thinkpad t61 whit archlinux and xubuntu in dual boot ^^)

Comment: My ISP ADSL internet is weird. It does not work if I connect the Ethernet cable directly in my computer nor putting it in another wifi modem. I am restrict to use wifi and their modem. It must have a network configuration that only works with their devices but I really do not know. Anyway, thanks for your help! I already use Linux on my not-so-old notebook. I am running a Linux for three years!

Comment: do you dosent have a router whit dhcp netwen your asdl and your pc ? by my self i have glassfiber connection :D

Comment: I will try. I am not that network expert! Haha thanks

Comment: no problem if it helps you can rank the question up pls ?

Answer (score 2):

Lenovo Thinkpad has Intel wireless device 7260. This is not compatible with kernel version earlier than 3.18.*. 
To solve the problem please update the kernel to the most updated kernel version supported by your ubuntu version. you can find the instruction to update the kernel [here](http://www.wikihow.com/Update-Ubuntu-Kernel).

Then update the 'additional Driver' from 'system settings'. Thats all.

Answer (score 1):

If *modinfo* returns nothing, then this relatively new device isn't covered by the relatively old kernel version included in 12.04. If you upgrade to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS or 14.10, it will be included by default. If you wish to remain with 12.04, it will be *extremely* difficult to compile the driver without any internet connection.

Please tell me which you prefer and I will then edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: So I will upgrade to the last last version. I installed the 12.04 because I had it on a flash drive. But really thanks for you help.